# Trying to order by value that has a one to many relationship - LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4

I have been using my good friend Google to find the solution to by problem and this is as far as I have got before running out of ideas

Basically I have 3 tables

Development has a 1 to many relationship with Property (A development can have many properties)
Property has a 1 to many relationship with PropertyRent (A property can have many rents)

The problem I am having is sorting by Rental Value, here is what I have so far:

```
var developmentListSorted = (from d in ContextEntity.Properties
                             where developments.Contains(d.Development.DevelopmentId)
                             orderby d.PropertyRents.Select(x=>x.PropertyRentValue).OrderBy(x=>x.CompareTo(x))
                             select d.Development).Distinct().ToList();
```

Now without the OrderBy, I get a nice unsorted list.  I really need to be able to sort by the PropertyRentValue.

The property 'development' is an array of ID's.

Please let me know if I need to clarify this further.

Many thanks.

Comment: I think the query you are trying to do doesn't make sense because you want distinct at the end - that will not work if you want to order by two levels deep one-to-many relations.

Comment: Got rid of the distinct and getting the same issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that ContextEntity.Developments gives you access to the developments

```
var developmentListSorted =
               from d in ContextEntity.Developments
                  where developments.Contains(d.DevelopmentId)
                  orderby
                    d.Properties.Min(x=>x.PropertyRents.Min(y=>y.PropertyRentValue))
                  select d;
```

This assumes you are sorting by the minimum rent value, you could change both occurances of `Min` to `Max` to get max value or even use `Average`